# installing php-memcached on centos 6.4 with php5.5

Tags: php, nginx, memcached, fastcgi

I just finished installing php FASTCGI (php-fpm) v.5.5 with Nginx. on a new Centos6.4

I'm trying to install memcached but encounter many issues..... here are my steps:

```
/bin/rpm -ivh http://ftp.uninett.no/linux/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm 
/bin/rpm -ivh http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm
yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-php55 install nginx php-common php-fpm php-mysqlnd
```

but when trying to add memcached:

```
yum install php-pecl-memcached.x86_64 (Extension to work with the Memcached caching daemon)
```

it's failing...:

```
> Resolving Dependencies
> --> Running transaction check
> ---> Package php-pecl-memcached.x86_64 0:1.0.0-1.el6 will be installed
> --> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20090626 for package: php-pecl-memcached-1.0.0-1.el6.x86_64
> --> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20090626 for package: php-pecl-memcached-1.0.0-1.el6.x86_64
> --> Processing Dependency: libmemcached.so.2(libmemcached_2)(64bit) for package: php-pecl-memcached-1.0.0-1.el6.x86_64
> --> Processing Dependency: libmemcached.so.2()(64bit) for package: php-pecl-memcached-1.0.0-1.el6.x86_64
> --> Running transaction check
> ---> Package libmemcached.x86_64 0:0.31-1.1.el6 will be installed
> ---> Package php-pecl-memcached.x86_64 0:1.0.0-1.el6 will be installed
> --> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20090626 for package: php-pecl-memcached-1.0.0-1.el6.x86_64
> --> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20090626 for package: php-pecl-memcached-1.0.0-1.el6.x86_64
> --> Finished Dependency Resolution Error: Package: php-pecl-memcached-1.0.0-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
>            Requires: php(zend-abi) = 20090626
>            Installed: php-common-5.5.6-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
>                php(zend-abi) = 20121212-64
>            Available: php-common-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64 (base)
>                php(zend-abi) = 20090626
>            Available: php-common-5.3.3-23.el6_4.x86_64 (updates)
>                php(zend-abi) = 20090626 Error: Package: php-pecl-memcached-1.0.0-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
>            Requires: php(api) = 20090626
>            Installed: php-common-5.5.6-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
>                php(api) = 20121113-64
>            Available: php-common-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64 (base)
>                php(api) = 20090626
>            Available: php-common-5.3.3-23.el6_4.x86_64 (updates)
>                php(api) = 20090626  You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem  You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles
> --nodigest
```

it worked fine on php 5.4....am i missing something?
thx.

Comment: Hey. `yum --enablerepo=remi install memcached` ?

Comment: yeap...that did it :) yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-php55 install php-pecl-memcached.x86_64

Comment: I'm glad that worked out for you.

Comment: @AnthonySterling you can add your comment as an answer so that the question could be marked as answered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Added answer according to comment :

```
yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-php55 install php-pecl-memcached.x86_64
```

Or as stated add permanent to yum.